# Is there a way to turn off the automatic/sticky positioning of the view on LIbreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Over the past years I have been using LibreOffice Calc a lot.

However, no matter how many times I have looked around in the Settings, I cannot seem to find a way to turn off the "auto-positioning" of the view of my file.

It happens on horizontal scrolling, when a cell does not align with the vertical border of the sidebar. The first column even persists to stay on it's original place.

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Do you mean [**View - Freeze Cells - Freeze First Column**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.0/en-US/text/scalc/guide/line_fix.html)?

Comment: @JohnSUN This helped me with the second problem, thank you. The first problem still remains.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand from the description what the first problem is. Is it about placing a very wide column on the screen? Or is something else bothering you?

Comment: The default scrolling behaviour in any direction is to scroll past 1 row (for vertical motion) or 1 column (for horizontal motion) for each scrolling "unit", rather than pixel-by-pixel "smooth scrolling". Is there a way for this to change?

Comment: Perhaps this page contains the answer to your question - [**#TDF-35287**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35287)? There are several more similar

Comment: Answer from documentfoundation developers https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34689 

> Donation will not make a difference, but any group of individuals can pool their money and hire a C++ freelancer to fix any bug in LibreOffice.

So I would be willing to drop some coins if there would be a bounty program for that